# Conditionally type a variable if a specific parameter is given

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to do a function that returns some data and this data can be modified with a middleware which is basically a callback that my function takes in its parameters.

Here's a simplified version of my function:

```
const parse = <T, M>(data: T, middleware?: (payload: T) => M) => {
  // how can I type this variable?
  let result; // something like `middleware ? M : T`

  if (middleware) {
    result = middleware(data) 
  } else {
    result = data;
  }
    
  return result;
}

// user is `any` when it should be `{ name: string; age: number }`
const user = parse({ name: "Bob" }, (data) => ({ ...data, age: 35 }))
```

How can I type the return of my function (aka `result`)? I could do something like `let result: T | M;` but then I'd get an error when trying to access a propriety that has been added to `M` in the middleware (`user.age` in this case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [function overloading](https://howtodoinjava.com/typescript/function-overloading/) for this:

```
// function signatures
function parse<T>(data: T): T;
function parse<T, M>(data: T, middleware: (payload: T) => M): M;

// function declaration
function parse <T, M>(data: T, middleware?: (payload: T) => M) {
    return middleware ? middleware(data) : data;
}

const bob = parse({ name: "Bob" }, (data) => ({ ...data, age: 35 }))
// bob has type { age: number, name: string }

const alice = parse({ name: "Alice" })
// alice has type { name: string }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwIYCcDOBTAPAFQD4AKAE1SlQC5F8BKG-AbgFgAoUSWBFDHAgDSIAsiXKVGQgLYxSpADbYA7hmw1iaAJ7y4qUozqIAvIREMRrNu07R4SNFmyJBIsRWq1pshctUB+dS0dPQNjU2FDAG92RFjEdGwoEHQkGTlFFQTEP0Q0n0zsMndDGnFUSwBfdnYIBEwoRAAjOEbjXkdiSMQwVCk1RAAiACEWgcQKoSLKQxNETsQAOiWyoVQAc36AZgBWcbo6dgB6Q6aWxAALVExEKE1kJy71-rAQKUbsdCEevpp69BgwGtxtU2LUwPVEKh5DAIE4jO0cPNvv0BgBBaGwsYVA5sY6QjFOS7XW73RBdZG-KD-QHAthAA)